# How to set up Atana Studio 3 Themes in Pydev

Tags: python, themes, aptana, pydev

I've installed the Aptana Studio 3 preview and noticed it has support for themes (such as a bespin style or Ruby envy) and I'd love to use the Bespin one in Pydev but so far I've had no luck getting it to work, anyone have a clue as to how to get it to work?

[Video showing the themes in action.](http://vimeo.com/8253946?hd=1)

Answer (score 1):

1. Window->Preferences
2. Aptana->Themes